# How to transfer in-memory redis data to an on disk database?

Tags: mongodb, redis, database

If I store data in redis for 1 hour, how would I go about storing the data into a database on disk after that one hour is up?

Comment: but then it wouldn't be an in-memory cache....!

Comment: I mean, the data stored in redis will expire after a set time(let's say one hour), I still want to keep that data but in a database, I'm only using redis for recent data.

Comment: @user2790999 According to above mentioned description It seems that data stored in redis has an expiry period of 1 hour and after its expiry period  data should be flushed from memory and copied to mongo database on disk .Please elaborate the above mentioned assumption